# Categories in media library

Tags: categories, uploads, media, library

I want to add a rather big sound collection to the media library. The problem is that i can't add category to the bunch of files while uploading them... I even can't add it to one uploading file.... And I can't find the way to solve this problem. It's a big work to add the category to thousands of sound files. Is it possible to add a tag field or a catagory field to the media library and include appropriate field to the uploading media library page?

The plugins in answer do not allow to set a category in the time of uploading...
probably it's time to add more features for users to work with media library in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this functionality by this plugins :

1. [wp-media-library-categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-media-library-categories)
2. [media-category-library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-category-library)

Comment: But they do not allow to set a category in the time of uploading...